# write php inside javascript alert

Tags: php, javascript, alert

I write PHP inside JS in the following way

```
alert(<?php echo __("Error-login") ?>);
```

`echo__("Error-login")` correlates with an xml to translate in two languages ​​with symfony, but now it does not work.

How do I fix this?

Comment: add `;` in `'<?php echo __("Error-login"); ?>'`

Comment: I hope php code in js works, only if the corresponding file name is saved as a .php file.

Answer (score 4):

You are missing quotes in the `alert()` call.

```
alert('<?php echo __("Error-login") ?>');
```

Answer (score 2):

Your line becomes

```
alert(Error-login);
```

As you can see, you are missing the quotes:

```
alert('Error-login');
```

If somebody uses quotes in the translation, this will also generate an error:

```
alert('Error's are here');
```

So you need to escape single quotes before you pass it to Javascript.

Comment: it does not work the same alert('<?php echo __("Error-login"); ?>')

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<?php echo '<script language="javascript">confirm("Do you want this?")</script>;'; ?>
```