# Wordpress: How can I pick plugins directory in my javascript file?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I need to access plugins directory in my customer javascript file. I know we have do have functions to retrieve plugins directory path using php function `plugins_url()`.

However, I need this to retrieve in my js file where I have to put some images.

Any ideas??

PS: My js file is saved as a javascript file and therefore, I can't use php tags in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `<?php echo plugins_url(); ?>` where you want to get the url in the js file.

For example:

```
var pluginUrl = '<?php echo plugins_url(); ?>' ;
```

Comment: my js file is saved as js and therefore, won't pick php tags

Comment: Why not? See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9631910/write-php-inside-javascript-alert

Comment: Then add that inline to the top of the page before the external JS.  I'd suggest creating a JSON object for different configuration options.  There's also a slicker way using the localization features of WP to configure JS but I don't have the information handy.

Comment: The echoed PHP needs to be encapsulated by quotes. But yes, this is one way to do it. The resultant can be passed to the external JS file via an argument, or it can be made globally accessible.

Comment: how can I make this one variable accessible globally??

Comment: Define it in a script tag before the external Javascript file is loaded.

Comment: This didn't work for me either, php wasn't parsed or executed and even more dangerously was still visible in script returned to user.

Answer (score 2):

It's actually quite easy...
In functions.php

> wp_enqueue_script( 'main', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/main.js', array('jquery'), '20151215', true );
>
> $translation_array = array( 'templateUrl' =>get_stylesheet_directory_uri() );       //after wp_enqueue_script
>
> wp_localize_script( 'main', 'jsVars', $translation_array );

then in the js-file:

```
var sitepath=jsVars.templateUrl+"/";
```

Edit: Just in case it's not understood completely:
The translation array is created and contains a key value pair
The array is then injected as jsVars (javascript variable) into the js scripts
So basically we (mis)use the translation array to inject variables to JS
with the wp_localize_script command.
off course instead of the templateUrl you can define all the params you want with PHP to inject their values into any js file you want.
In this example we inject the template Url into the main js script via jsVars, but it can be any variable into any js script

Comment: This answer is the WordPress way

Answer (score 0):

I've got the result just by assigning the real plugin url:

```
let pluginUrl = "../wp-content/plugins/YOUR_PLUGIN_FOLDER_NAME/";
```

Comment: That may work in some instances, for instance my local works well with that path but it does not when applied to a live server.