# WordPress - Plugin - enqueue image files from WP plugin directory in a JS-file

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, plugins

I'm new with creating plugins for WP and I'm still learning. I have two questions concerning the same issue:

1: 
First I included the js-file in my plugins **php-file**:

```
function theme_name_scripts() {
wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/example.js');
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts' );
```

It works but what I want to do is to locate it from my plugins url (wordpress/wp-content/plugins/example), not from my template directory. How do I do this?

2:
In my **js-file**, I need to include some image files from the plugin base url (wordpress/wp-content/plugins/example/pix). This script worked when not used as a plugin:

```
window.onload=function()
{

/* Example */

bp='/pix/', // base url of my images

imgnum=4, // number of images
thumb1=document.getElementById('thumb1'), // id of changing image
combobox1=document.getElementById('selection1'); // id of combobox.

combobox1.onchange=function()
{
thumb1.src=bp+'imagefile'+this.value+'.png';
}
```

I understand that `bp='/pix/',` is wrong. But what is correct? I want to load the images from a folder in `template_directory`. How do I do this? I have read through these two threads but I cant seem to figure it out:

[Wordpress: How can I pick plugins directory in my javascript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12426710/wordpress-how-can-i-pick-plugins-directory-in-my-javascript-file)

[write php inside javascript alert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9631910/write-php-inside-javascript-alert)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`plugins_url()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url) to enqueue scripts from the plugin directory.

In your case, it would be something like:

```
function theme_name_scripts() {
  wp_register_script('script-name', plugins_url('js/example.js', __FILE__));
}
```

To make the plugin url path available in javascript, you can use [`wp_localize_script()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) in combination with for example [`plugin_dir_url()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugin_dir_url) (which you also can use above I guess...).

So the end result would be something like:

```
function theme_name_scripts() {
  // register your script
  wp_register_script('script-name', plugins_url('js/example.js', __FILE__));
  // or
  // wp_register_script('script-name', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'js/example.js');

  // make variables available in javascript
  wp_localize_script('script-name', 'wordpress_vars', 
                     array('plugin_path' => plugin_dir_url(__FILE__)));
}
```

And in your javascript you will have the `wordpress_vars` variable available. Your plugin path will be `wordpress_vars.plugin_path`.

Note that I have modified the `wp_localize_script` to send an array as its 3rd argument.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @jeroen but it didn't work. Can it be that I am working on localhost? Could this affect the plugins_url path?

Comment: @TobiasStyrbjörnNordin If WordPress is setup correctly, the server should not matter. Which does not work, or both? I may have made an edit concerning your second question. Also note that I have put in 2 options for your first problem (one is commented out).

Comment: Thanks for the input! I tried both plugins_url and plugins_dir_url. None working. I can still locate the js-file from my template url. I'll try that, for now, since my biggest concern is locating the image files. Is this the proper way to enqueue the png-files in my js-file: `bp='wordpress_vars.plugin_path/myplugin/imgfolder/',`